# pushing a folder to a bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, machg

I have a folder(b) inside another folder(a) which was already pushed into a repository, and i want to push folder(b) to the bitbucket using macHg but I want it to push it so in bitbucket it looks like a new folder, right now when i pushed it it just made a new head it didn't put the whole folder in there. How can I push the whole folder so on bitbucket would look like

Folder A

- Folder B

  - file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `hg status`, what do you get? You should get output like this:

```
zck@zck-desktop:~/my-test$ hg status
? a/b/file
```

The question mark means that mercurial doesn't know about `a/b/file` yet. So let's tell it to track the file. This is just a local command, nothing will hit the remote server yet.

```
zck@zck-desktop:~/my-test$ hg add a/b/file
zck@zck-desktop:~/my-test$ hg status
A a/b/file
```

The `A` means that the file was just added. Now we just need to commit (which is another local command).

```
zck@zck-desktop:~/my-test$ hg commit -m "added a/b/file, with contents in it?"
```

Finally, we need to push the changeset up to the remote server. This is the only command we've done that touches the remote server.

```
zck@zck-desktop:~/my-test$ hg push
```